# How to use BackgroundWorker with main thread functions?

Tags: c#

Ok, I was trying not to be too specific but, here it goes:

```
    public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime startTeste = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime finishTeste = startTeste.AddSeconds(mTeste + sTeste);

        while(DateTime.Now <= finishTeste) //enquanto o teste nao terminar
        {
            if(backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) 
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(DateTime.Now - startTeste).TotalSeconds + 30);


            //AtualizarVal();
            Teste();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000); 
        }
    }

 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        tProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; //atualiza as barras de progresso
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Cancelled)     //Caso seja cancelado o BGW
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thread got canceled");
        }

        if(nTeste == nTestes)
        {
            buttonSTART.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Job done");
        }
    }
```

The function Teste() is:

```
    public void Teste()
    {
        tbtatual.Text = "12";
    }
```

The only thing I want to do, is to write to a textbox, every 30seconds, and I have to it in a thread, because I'm going to write in more textboxes and I'm going to send controls via RS-232, because of those controls and of a Timer I need to use the thread, so that when my program sends and receives the data via RS-232 doesn't mess up with my timers.

Maybe this is too much code, but I think this way I'll make you understand what happens.

Comment: Do you want to stick to Backgroundworker or are you open to using async/await/Task? Are you aware of the [ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.8) functionality of BGW?

Comment: We need more information. Do you not have access to the tbtatual TextBox, or is there another error?

Comment: In the DoWork function you cannot access any UI elements. You have to use RunWorkerCompleted. I would suggest using async/await anyway since it's usually  more flexible and more modern.

Comment: @Joelius "You cannot" seems a little bit too strict. You actually can with doing some serious "bending the rules" (Like marshalling calls cross thread). But I think we agree, that it should not be done.

Comment: @Fildor well okay maybe I should have specified. You definitiely should not use a BackgroundThread for updating the UI. I'd go as far as saying that that's almost the opposite of what BackgroundThreads are for (apart from reporting progress).

Comment: "My main problem is not do this, but if I can figure this out, I can implement the rest of my code." What is the main problem then? We need to know what you need because what you're doing right now doesn't make enough sense for me to come up with a good solution for you.

Comment: Ok, I was trying not to be too specific but, here it goes:

Answer (score -1):

You can't access UI components(Text boxes,MessegeBoxes etc) from other threads .These components controlled from UI Thread Example;

```
public void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 //After some Work Done

     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new 
       ThreadStart(delegate
       {
             Teste();
       }));
}
```

Comment: Well "You can't access UI components(Text boxes,MessegeBoxes etc) from other threads" is true but I don't think the code you posted is a good solution. This is not only hard to read but bad practice since it looks like what you're doing here is exactly what the RunWorkerCompleted event is for. This will be invoked on the main thread again where you have access to the UI-elements.

Comment: @Joelius For intermediate UI-Interaction, there is also `ReportProgress()` - but I don't know if it fits OP's requirements. It's meant for just that - report some progress back to the UI. Like updating a ProgressBar and the like.

Comment: If the BackgroundWorker was created from the UI thread, then the RunWorkerCompleted event will also be raised on the UI thread.If it was created from a background thread, the event will be raised on an undefined background thread.If you dont know in this context who is creating background thread

Comment: @phantasm If you start BGWs from other BGWs you have much bigger problems than updating a field in the UI ... :D

Comment: @phantasm well that's true.. I just assumed that the BackgroundWorker was created on the UI-thread. Since OP seems to be a beginner I think he might have placed it from the toolbar which would also create it on the UI-thread.

Comment: @phantasm I'd love to but unfortunately I'm still unsure about what OP actually wants. It seems like they're trying to update the UI from a BackgroundWorker. I don't know why you would do such a thing and I would never propose to a beginner to do so. Maybe what they need is aync/await or maybe they want progress-reporting. We didn't even get to see the rest of the DoWork method yet (or is there no rest?).. They said "My main problem is not do this.." so what is it then?